# OnPrintDialogClose method was not fired after print preview closed

Tags: javascript, html, printjs

Hi I am using PrintJs javascript library. I assigned a call back function in OnPrintDialogClose option. It didn't fired immediately after the print preview window was closed but it only fired after I switched to new browser tab or I press Alt+Tab on Windows OS. Does anybody know why it didn't triggered after print preview window close.

This is my [Codepen sample](https://codepen.io/Lute/project/editor/XVrezP#0)

This is my javascript code snippet.

```
<script>
    var afterPreviewClose = function(){ 
       window.location = "index.html"; 
    };
    $("#btnPrint").on("click",function(){ 
       printJS({ 
          printable: 'print-area',
          type: 'html', 
          onPrintDialogClose: afterPreviewClose,
          css: 'styles/styles.css' }); 
       }); 
</script>
```

Comment: The issue seems to be related with Chrome on windows. Here is a link for the active thread in the lib repo: https://github.com/crabbly/Print.js/issues/348

Answer (score 2):

I tried slebetman's solution in the following link https://github.com/crabbly/Print.js/issues/348

```
let focuser = setInterval(() => window.dispatchEvent(new Event('focus')), 500);

printJs({

    printable: url,

    onPrintDialogClose: () => {

    clearInterval(focuser);

    // do your thing..

},

onError: () => {

    clearInterval(focuser);

    // do your thing..

  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I end up using normal javascript print features instead of using the library because immediate redirect to another page after the print dialog close is a must feature for my page. I also reported that issues to the PrintJs team so that they can review it. My current solution for this problem is using normal **onafterprint** function implementation as follows.

**Main Page (index.html)**

```
 <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"> 
    </script>
    <style>
       .print-area {
          width: 300px;
       }

       .print-area table {
          width: 100%;
       }

       .print-area table,
       th,
       td {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 1px solid;
        text-align: center;
       }

       .print-area th {
         background-color: grey;
         color: white;
       }

       @media print {
           .print-area {
              width: 300px;
              height: 400px;
           }

           .print-area table {
              width: 100%;
           }

           .print-area table,
           th,
           td {
             border-collapse: collapse;
             border: 1px solid;
             text-align: center;
           }

           .print-area th {
              background-color: grey;
              color: white;
           }

           .no-print {
             display: none;
           }
       }
     </style>
  </head>

 <body>
    <div class="print-area">
       <table>
         <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Address</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Si Thu </td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>Yangon</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>WWK </td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>Yangon</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div class="no-print" style="margin-top:50px;">
     <button id="btnPrint">Print</button>
   </div>

     <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#btnPrint").on("click", function () {
                window.onafterprint = function () {
                   console.log("onafterprint function fired");
                   window.location = "nextpage.html";
                };
                window.print();
              });
         });
     </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Page to be redirected after print dialog close (nextpage.html)**

```
<html>
   <head>
       <title>Next Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <h2>This is redirected page</h2>
   </body>
</html>
```